How to control CupertinoContextMenu dividers thickness
I want to control the thickness of CupertinoContextMenu's divider's, I didn't see this property in Theme class and also I was not able to spot customization on widgets properties, how would that be possible?
My code :
return CupertinoContextMenu.builder(
  builder: (context, animation) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
          (mainAxisCount - animation.value),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
          (mainAxisCount - animation.value),
      child: cardBox(context,
          ratioFactor: animation.value < sizeLimit
              ? null
              : (size * animation.value),
          shatter: shatter,
          actions: actions,
          animated: animation.value != 0.0),
    );
  },
  actions: contextMenuActions,
);

Current result:

It's expected to be able to change the thickness a little bit.
Expected UI


Can you include sample code snippet and expected ui?

@Md.YeasinSheikh Sure just added.

actually it stills missing necessary snippet to reproduce the issue, such as contextMenuActions hasnt been define here

You cannot directly change the divider's thickness. But there is a work around
Refering :https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/54e66469a9/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/context_menu.dart#L155
You can recreate this into a context_menu_extended.dart and simply in the _ContextMenuSheet widget.
Change the width of Decorated Box as bellow.
DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      top: BorderSide(
                        color: CupertinoDynamicColor.resolve(
                          _borderColor,
                          context,
                        ),
                        width: 0.4, // Change the width here.
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  position: DecorationPosition.foreground,
                  child: action,
                ),


I didn't want to do this but looks like I have to, Thanks for the answer.
